# Solidity: Are these sentences the same? Or do they mean different things?

Tags: solidity

In order to calling a function 'isContract', with the parameter 'to' being an address, are valid both ways? :

```
   to.isContract() 

   isContract(to)
```

Does Solidity allow both ways?
I have found both in different codes, and I don't know if just 'isContract(to)' is the right one, or if 'to.isContract()' means another different thing.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're not the same.

`to.isContract()` suggests that you have defined an interface (in your code) that defines a `isContract()` function, and that the contract deployed at the `to` address implements this interface.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface ExternalContract {
    function isContract() external returns (bool);
}

contract MyContract {
    function foo() external {
        ExternalContract to = ExternalContract(address(0x123));
        bool returnedValue = to.isContract(); // calling `to`'s function `isContract()`
    }
}
```

`isContract(to)` calls an `external` or `internal` function in your contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyContract {
    function foo() external {
        address to = address(0x123);
        bool returnedValue = isContract(to); // calling your function `isContract()`
    }
    
    function isContract(address to) internal returns (bool) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

Edit: I forgot about one more case - using a library containing the `isContract()` function for an address. Example OpenZeppelin implementation: [definition](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L19), [usage](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L342).

```
library AddressLibrary {
    function isContract (address _address) {
        return true;
    }
}

contract MyContract {
    using AddressLibrary for address;

    function foo() external {
        address to = address(0x123);
        bool returnedValue to.isContract(); // calling your function `isContract(to)`
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Petr Hejda for your help! I have no reputation in order to vote your comment, but thanks a lot.

Comment: @KevinFlynn Glad to have helped. If the answer was useful, you can mark it as accepted. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers